# No expected exceptions are thrown while testing Spring Boot Repositories

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, unit-testing, junit

I want to check some validations while performing CRUD operations on my business object `Product`:

`Product` class:

```
@Getter
@Setter
@Entity
@Table(name = "PRODUCT")
public class Product extends AbstractEntity<Long> {

    @Column(nullable = false)
    private String name;

    private String description;

    @Column(nullable = false)
    @Min(value = 0)
    private Float cost;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "product", fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @Fetch(value = FetchMode.SELECT)
    private Set<ProductRating> productRatings;

}
```

When I am running my Spring Boot application I got my desired exception (`java.sql.SQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException`) while adding `Product` without obligatory `name`:

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class QlturkaApplication implements CommandLineRunner {

    @Autowired
    private ProductRepository productRepository;

    @Autowired
    private UserRepository userRepository;

    @Autowired
    private ProductRatingRepository productRatingRepository;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(QlturkaApplication.class, args);
    }

    @Override
    public void run(String... args) throws Exception {

        Product p = new Product();
        productRepository.save(p);

    }
}
```

But when I run test, `Product` without `name` is getting saved in database, got persisted and has unique ID, no exception is thrown, why?

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@DataJpaTest
@AutoConfigureTestDatabase(replace = AutoConfigureTestDatabase.Replace.NONE)
@ContextConfiguration(classes = WebSecurityConfig.class)
public class ProductRepositoryTest {

    @Autowired
    private ProductRepository productRepository;


    @Test(expected = SQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException.class)
    public void nullProductNameThrowsError() {
        //java.sql.SQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: Column 'cost' cannot be null
        Product product = new Product();
        product.setName(null);
        productRepository.save(product);
        System.out.println(product.getId());

    }

    public void afterTest(Product p) {
        productRepository.delete(p);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Because [data jpa tests](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/api/org/springframework/boot/test/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/DataJpaTest.html) by default rollback at the end of each test, and you never explictly flush in your test. So no flush is ever made, so nothing is ever inserted in the table, so the database can't tell you that you forgot to insert the name.

Call `flush()` in your test, after saving (or call `saveAndFlush()`).